# Can stored procedure in MySql 5.0.x be encrypted?

Tags: mysql

In Microsoft Sql it is possible to encrypted stored procedures with

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo 
WITH ENCRYPTION 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT 'foo' 
END
```

This stops people looking at stored procedures code.

How can I do this in **MySql** 5.0.x ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not do this in MySQL. See bug #[4210](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4210).

[Edit]: The comment from [Leonidas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57510/leonidas) on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501122/can-stored-procedure-in-mysql-5-0-x-be-encrypted/501145#501145) to this question needs to be out there for anyone to read, so I'm quoting it here:

> Obfuscation can be reversed. I found
>   at least one product via Google, that
>   promises to reveal the SP-code. So I
>   think/hope that the MySQL-team won't
>   bother with "security by obscurity" or
>   even worse "intellectual asset
>   protection" (as described in the bug
>   4210).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its been [requested](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4210) [before](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19516) but I don't know if they're considering it.

Comment: That request is a duplicate of Bug#4210

Comment: Actually, that's 2 different links, one of them is #4210 ;)

Comment: My bad, didn't see that the link was actually two links :)

Comment: Obfuscation can be reversed. I found at least one product via Google, that promises to reveal the SP-code. So I think/hope that the MySQL-team won't bother with "security by obscurity" or even worse "intellectual asset protection" (as described in the bug 4210).