# Can I obfuscate the SQL code in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, obfuscation

I'm trying to find some way to obfuscate SQL code in MySQL.

In the Oracle databases exists the "wrap" funcionality, but I didn't found some similar. Some ideas?

The final goal is that the client has some difficuties to understand the code.

Comment: Mind if I ask why you'd want to do this? It's just that we can help better if we know your goal instead of an intermediate objective...

Comment: They'll never find it if you put your code into stored procedures.

Comment: My goals are the procedures and functions cos' I want to be more difficult to read.

Comment: I would really hate to come behind you and have to maintain that code.

Comment: Unprofessional and unethical. If you wish to protect your intellectual property, this is not the way.

Comment: mysql does not offer anything like oracle's wrap tool. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501122/can-stored-procedure-in-mysql-5-0-x-be-encrypted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think MySQL do not have the ability to obfuscate the code. You can encapsulate the whole SQL query code by creating a [**STORED PROCEDURE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html), although not encapsulated but at least your whole SQL query is not shown when used inside your code (*PHP, .Net, and the like...*).

Comment: easier to obfuscate or not reveal source code than to prevent access to store procedure. MySQL will show you the source for the stored procedure using SHOW CREATE ...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have any obfuscation abilities - you could write some code that would be confusing to read by having some other table with defined values that you could use IF statements against to make your code difficult to read...

```
SELECT co1, co2, IF(3 > 18, co3, '') AS co3 FROM table INNER JOIN...
```

etc... or using COUNTs as parameters in conditional statements is as best as you're going to get (obviously performance may become an issue depending on how "obfuscated").

Comment: by creating that, you are adding extra work for server. Why not use `Stored Procedure`?

Comment: I am not suggesting that anyone use this technique, especially on a large amount of data... nor would I ever really want to obfuscate my own code - giving OP options, we don't fully understand the circumstances in why he wants to obfuscate his queries, but this is an option.