# aes_encrypt function doesn't work with mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, aes

When I use `AES_ENCRYPT()` in my query

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(a.chat_id,'AA') AS chat_id FROM vw_chat_members_name a
```

It is working as expected but when I try to use in procedure it returns `null` column???

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE aa() BEGIN SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(a.chat_id,'AA') AS chat_id FROM vw_chat_members_name a; END
```

Comment: i have just learned that mysql stored procedures doesn't have cryption support. Sorry for question.

Comment: *mysql stored procedures doesn't have cryption support* Where did you learn that?  It isn't accurate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501122/can-stored-procedure-in-mysql-5-0-x-be-encrypted

Comment: That appears to refer to the encryption of the *definition* of the stored program -- not the use of encryption functions. (Kudos to you for trying to find the answer, though, and for providing the citation).

Answer (score 0):

The default key length for the built-in AES functions is 128 bits.  Your example, as shown, uses only a 16 bit key.

Try it with a 128 bit key, such as `'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt

Comment: it's still same. I also tried this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224515/why-is-aes-decrypt-returning-null but this doesn't work too.